# Barcode quality issues

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner, barcode-printing, code128

Is it possible to create 28 bits bar code of quality A with width of 3 1/2 inches.

Details: Code 128 bar code

Bits: 28 bit code

Can you please share the dimensions of bar code including quiet zones which will make bar code lie between class A or class B quality.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean "28 characters" not "28 bits".

Essentially, the barcode width depends on the dots-per-inch (dpi) pitch of the printer you are using and the internal structure of the data.

For all-numeric data (which has best compression in code128) there should be no problem fitting 28 numeric characters into 3.5", even with a 200dpi model like a 2844. a 3844 would give you 300 dpi for better quality at a higher price.

Zebra firmware automatically compresses the barcode produced to the best internal sequence to produce the shortest physical code - which depends on the precise data to be encoded. If your code is all-numeric, that will be the shortest possible (and a constant width). If your data always follows the same pattern (eg 10 numerics, 6 alphas,12 numerics) then that will also produce a constant width (but it will be longer than all-numeric). All-alphas will yield the longest code. Other combinations may generate a shorter code depending on the length of any "run" of sequential numerics.